# Unable to accept cookies with python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cookies

I'm trying to accept a cookie banner, but it doesn't work. The code is the following, what am I doing wrong?

I get the following error: *selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element*

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.ticketcorner.ch/event/disney-in-concert-dreams-become-true-hallenstadion-13050005/')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmpwelcomebtnyes > a > svg') 
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver,25).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmpwelcomebtnyes > a > svg'))).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: It's within a shadowroot.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Thank you so much for the tip! It worked.

If anyone ever finds this and doesn't know how to go about the shadow root issue, watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj9A73okFb8

In my case the solution is: 

driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#cmpwrapper").shadowRoot.querySelector("#cmpbntyestxt")').click()

Answer (score 1):

If you look the HTML you will see that the button to accept the cookies is contained inside a `#shadow-root (open)`. To get rid of it we can exploit its parent `#cmpwrapper` in this way

```
shadow_parent = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmpwrapper')
outer = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_parent)
inner = outer.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmpbntyestxt')
inner.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Selenium 3 and 4 you'll get a dict error with.

```
driver.get('https://www.ticketcorner.ch/event/disney-in-concert-dreams-become-true-hallenstadion-13050005/')

shadow_parent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#cmpwrapper")))
shadow_root_dict  = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_parent)
print(shadow_root_dict)
shadow_root_id = shadow_root_dict['shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf']
shadow_root = WebElement(driver, shadow_root_id)
shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#cmpwelcomebtnyes > a").click()
```